# Can I tweak the returned address label from HERE's reverse geocode API?

Tags: here-api, reverse-geocoding

I would like the address label in the response from HERE's reverse geocode API to only contain street, house number and city. Is that possible by setting some request parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The answer directly contains the parsed address so you can chose whatever field is relevant for you:
[image]

Comment: True. But since addresses are formatted differently in different countries I don't want to do it myself. In sweden we write street name first and then street number (Avenue Henri Martin 60" so I would like HERE to take care of the formatting for me. I want to specify what Address items I need and want the Label string to include them formatted according the provided country/language